# Constant compile error after 64 bit Office upgrade

Tags: microsoft-office

Since I recently updated my MS Office to the 64 bit versions using the Microsoft Updater, I am constantly receiving the following message in Excel: "Compile error: The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute."

[image: Mac Excel error message]

This happens when I start Excel without opening a file, when I open a file and whenever I enter data. It has made my Excel basically useless for doing any new work.

The Excel about box reports the version as Excel 15.25.1 (160826). I am running OS X 10.11.6 with all the latest updates.

My Googling has only shown references to VBA code, but I have not loaded any custom VBA. I am open to partial workarounds as well.

I'm running MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the [CoolProp](http://coolprop.sourceforge.net/) plugin. This became aparent when I went to Tools|Macro|Visual Basic Editor and saw the various `Private Declare` statements, which all require an extra `PtrSafe` as per the dialog box.